# How to set right input to "while read line"?

Tags: shell-script

I my code I have while cycle which reads from file:

```
teams=()
status=()
novy=true
j=0
k=0

while read line; do

  name=$( echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 1 - ) 
  
  for i in "${teams[@]}"; do
    if [ "$i" = "$name" ]; then
      novy=false
      
      c=$( echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 3 - )
      status[$k]="${status[$k]}+$c"
      
      break
    fi
    k=$(( k+1 ))
    novy=true
  done
  
  if "$novy"; then
    teams[$j]="$name"
    status[$j]=$( echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 3 - )
    j=$(( j + 1 )) 
    novy=false
  fi
  
  k=0

done < ms.txt
```

But now I want to modify input `ms.txt` so I tried this:

```
input=$( cat ms.txt )

  some modifiations of input (by echo "$input" I verified that the input is in right form)

echo "$input" | while read line; do

  name=$( echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 1 - ) 
  
  for i in "${teams[@]}"; do
    if [ "$i" = "$name" ]; then
      novy=false
      
      c=$( echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 3 - )
      status[$k]="${status[$k]}+$c"
      
      break
    fi
    k=$(( k+1 ))
    novy=true
  done
  
  if "$novy"; then
    teams[$j]="$name"
    status[$j]=$( echo "$line" | cut -d ":" -f 3 - )
    j=$(( j + 1 )) 
    novy=false
  fi
  
  k=0

done
```

But now the code doesn't work, I don't know why. The while cycle doesn't read the input same as before and it prints some errors.

Comment: Also state what you want. You don't ask a question. Do you want help with some modifications of input, or do you want help with something that doesn't work well anymore? Or do you want help with something else?

Comment: Ok thank you, I thought that it is not important. :)

Comment: I want to help how to modify the input, in the first case I use `done < ms.txt` and that works, but I don't know how to modify `ms.txt` and the modified input pass to while cycle.

Comment: Without knowing the input and the modifications, and without seeing the error messages, it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: What you can do: Add `set -x` before code blocks that behave unexpectedly, and `set +x` after them. That will print the commands including values of variables before they are executed.

Comment: @Freddy Yes, thank you. I don't understand it well but I changed `done < ms.txt` for `done < <(echo "$input")` (it was written there) and it works. :) :D